# How did House Resolution 367 pass on the same day as introduced without a 2/3 majority?

Tags: united-states

[House resolution 367](http://beta.congress.gov/bill/113th/house-resolution/367/text?q=%7B%22search%22%3a%5B%22%20368%22%5D%7D) waives the requirement of clause 6(a) of rule XIII for resolutions on October 7th 2013. The clause 6(a) of rule XIII has the following text:

> 6.(a) A report by the Committee on Rules on a rule, joint rule, or the order of business may not be called up for consideration on the
>   same day it is presented to  the House except—
>
> (1) when so determined by a vote of two-thirds of the Members voting,
>   a quorum being present;
>
> (2) in the case of a resolution proposing only to waive a requirement
>   of clause 4 or of clause 8 of rule XXII concerning the availability of
>   reports; or
>
> (3) during the last three days of a session of
>   Congress.

This rule prevents resolutions from being voted upon on the same day as they are introduced, as far as I understand it. I can see how HR 367 can waive this rule for HR 368, but I'm confused on how House Resolution 367 itself managed to avoid this rule, as it seems to have been passed at the same day as it was introduced. The sites I looked up indicate that HR 367 was introduced and passed on the same day, on September 30th ([congress.gov](http://beta.congress.gov/bill/113th-congress/house-resolution/367/all-actions/?q=%7B%22search%22%3A%5B%22+368%22%5D%7D) and [govtrack.us](http://www.govtrack.us/congress/bills/113/hres367)).

What am I missing here? Did HR 367 pass without a two-thirds majority on the same day? And if yes, how did it manage to get around rule XIII 6(a) or why did that rule not apply to it?

Answer (score 2):

From the "actions" tab of HR 367:

> 09/30/2013-5:25pm     Considered as privileged matter. (consideration: CR H6021-6030)
>   Type of Action: Floor Consideration
>   Action By: House of Representatives

Privileged matters may be considered the same day they are brought to the House. In fact, they *can't* do anything else until the privileged motion has been dealt with. Unless another privileged motion supersedes it.

Comment: I haven't found the citation in their formal rules, but Jefferson's Manual (which the rules differ to) discusses privileged matters in section XXXIII. http://www.constitution.org/tj/tj-mpp.htm